# Issues with phpmyadmin login in

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have an issue with phymyadmin logining as root so that I am able to create DB. I have the follow config.inc.php configuration

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'Neo';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password';
```

I was able to start the server with with 
    mysqld --init-file=C:\mysql-init.txt

in that file i was able to include

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

The issue is after I stop this mysqld instance it goes back to only allowing me to view certain dbs with clean copies of phpmyadmin

I can't view the users tab nor create db

I have remove all sql installation and Program Files, x86, and Program Data subfolders and reinstalled

I don't want to have this hard code in a file a start up because eventually i want to setup privileges for certain users.

Any assistance would... my there is a way to override the view of users or something?

Comment: I did clear the web cache

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're basically saying that when you stop mysqld and start it again, anything you've changed in the database gets reverted to the old/clean version? Tell us about your setup, where did you get MySQL (from mysql.com or part of a kit?), what OS you're using, etc.

Comment: You shouldn't need to run the init-file more than once; doing that should persist across stopping and starting the daemon. Also, your root user should have already had those permissions anyway, so it's very strange that you have to set them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Wich version of MySql and PhpMyAdmin you run ?

If you start with new clean installation and set config.inc.php like this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhostconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

you can login for the first time, without password and set privileges for all users